# How to properly return values when using 'this' in an 'constructor' and the prototype methods of the object?

Tags: javascript, object, methods, prototype, this

For live code sample checkout my: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/matthewharwood/pen/qdLZvg?editors=001)

**Question:** How can I make sure that `p1.prototype.setFirst()` & `p1.prototype.fullName()` return the proper values while still using `this`?

```
var Person = function(){
     this.firstName = "Penelope";
     this.lastName = "Barrymore";

}
Person.prototype.fullName = function () {
  return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
}
Person.prototype.setFirst = function () {
  return this.firstName = "mark"
}
var p1 = new Person();
p1.prototype.setFirst()
console.log(p1.prototype.fullName());
```

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: ... And not `p1.setFirst();'?

Comment: @Jacob I'm just experiementing with javascript seeing whats possible.  Which doesn't always result in what's practical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really have to call via the prototype like that, you can do:

```
Person.prototype.setFirst.call(p1);
```

...and:

```
Person.prototype.fullName.call(p1);
```

`call` and `apply` are the easiest ways to change `this`.

If you want reference to a version of a function where `this` is *bound* to it, use `bind`:

```
var myFullName = Person.prototype.fullName.bind(p1);
myFullName(); // this will be p1
```

...but of course, this is the natural thing to do:

```
p1.fullName()
```

And if you want to get the prototype through the object, you can use:

```
p1.__proto__
```

...or:

```
p1.constructor.prototype
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/matthewharwood/pen/qdLZvg?editors=001 it's still coming up undefined.  I know p1.fullName() will work just fine.  I was accually trying to wrap my head around .bind(), .call() and .apply().  Regardless why is it still undefined?

Comment: I've made a huge mistake. Should have noticed that `p1.prototype` is not valid; `Person.prototype` is, but `p1.prototype` is undefined. `p1.__proto__` is the way to get the prototype of an object, or `p1.constructor.prototype`. Updated.

Comment: Basically, `prototype` is counter-intuitively how you set the prototype for _instances of a constructor_, whereas `__proto__` is how you get the prototype object of an instance.